# Connect to Signalr in Nifi

Tags: signalr, apache-nifi

I'd like to connect to a SignalR-server in nifi. Is there any processor in nifi to connect to singalr and receive asynchronous notifications? If not, anyone has any suggestion?

Comment: Theoretically possible to use java/groovy library inside executegroovyscript. But better to write own processor using java. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/java-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0